# Behaviour of a complex series on the boundary of the disk of convergence

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I would like to ask you for a hint if the series $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{nz^{n}}{2^n}$$ with the radius of convergence $2$ may happen to converge conditionally on the boundary. It obviously does not converge absoutely for $|z|=2$ since the series becomes $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}n$, which is divergent.

My second question would be how to check the boundary behaviour of $\sum^{\infty}_{n=2}\frac{(-1)^{n}z^{n}}{\ln n}$.

Comment: How about one question at a time?

Comment: @Chris So I would get $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}ne^{ni \theta}$ but how do I know that it diverges?

Comment: @Theta Term test as my answer shows is the simplest way to go.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Could you clarify why it also handles conditional convergence?

Comment: It doesn't handle any convergence.  It only shows divergence.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt But doesn't it show divergence of the series of absolute values only?

Comment: It does.  Divergence comes in only one form, divergence.  You can't "conditionally diverge" or "absolutely diverge".  You just diverge.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I mean, $\frac {(-1)^{n}}{n}$ series converges, $|\frac {(-1)^{n}}{n}|$ does not.

Comment: Yes.  You are thinking about whether a series converges conditionally or absolutely.  But this is not the case for divergence.  It either diverges, or it converges.  If it converges, then it may converge conditionally or absolutely, but there is no "if" for when it diverges.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I simply couldn't convince myself that divergence of absolute values is somehow equivalent to divergence without absolute values. It seems somewhat surprising, but nevertheless thank you very much for your explanation.

Comment: It is not divergence of absolute values.  It is the term test.  You seem to be a bit confused, so I recommend going back to your notes :-)

Comment: Notice that I didn't sum anything in the first part of my answer.  If I were summing, then I'd be testing for absolute convergence.  Instead, I was taking the limit of the absolute value of the nth term.  That is called the term test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, we can see that if $|z|=2$, then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{nz^n}{2^n}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n|z|^n}{2^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n2^n}{2^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}n=+\infty$$

Thus, it fails the term test.

---

For the second question, we can see that the radius of convergence is $1$ by the ratio test, and if $z=-1$, it diverges by the comparison test.  If $z=e^{i\theta}$ for $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi)$, then we have

$$\left|\sum_{n=2}^N(-1)^nz^n\right|=\left|\frac{1-e^{i(\theta+\pi)(N+1)}}{1-e^{i(\theta+\pi)}}\right|\le\frac2{|1-e^{i(\theta+\pi)}|}$$

$$\frac1{\ln(n)}\to0,\frac1{\ln(n)}<\frac1{\ln(n+1)}$$

Thus, it is bounded for every $\theta\ne\pm\pi$ and converges by the Dirichlet test.